# How to verify jquery cookie.js compatability?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

Is jquery.cookie.js compatible with jquery-1.10.1 version? I get the following error:

Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'cookie'

Though I checked the below links -

[$.cookie is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034190/cookie-is-not-a-function/4034220#4034220)

[Error: $.cookie is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815803/error-cookie-is-not-a-function)

[jQuery $.cookie is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function)

none helped to solve the issue. Is there any site from where I will get details about jquery.cookie.js compatibility with JQuery versions?
Appreciate suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to debug a non-minified version of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me with the [latest version](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) of `$.cookie` + jQuery `1.10.1`:

```
$.cookie('foo', true);
console.log($.cookie('foo'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2xHP/

Comment: which makes clear that the issue is not caused by jquery version. Thank you @Johan.

Comment: @mystackOverflow No problem. It sounds to me like you're trying to use `$.cookie` before the script is loaded.

Comment: I verified that probability too. But cookie.js is loaded after jquery.@Johan

Comment: Latest version link is broken.